# Java: Android: SQLite: Doing Multiple Inserts Using a For Loop

Tags: java, android, sqlite, for-loop, insert

Please review the following piece of code:

```
try {
          db.beginTransaction();
          db.execSQL(DBConstants.PRAG_FOR_KEYS_ON);

          db.execSQL(DBConstants._BLDG_CREATE);
          db.execSQL(DBConstants._BLDG_INDEX);
          for(int x = 0; x < 28; x = x+1){
              db.execSQL(DBConstants._BLDG_INSERT+x);
          }

          db.execSQL(DBConstants.PRAG_FOR_KEYS_OFF);
          db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
          db.endTransaction();
        }
```

Each of the insert constants (representing a row of new data) are numbered thus:

```
public static final String _BLDG_INSERT0 = "<SQL insert statement>"
```

...all the way up to 28 ("_BLDG_INSERT28").

Is there ANY way i can execute these SQL statements in a for loop? If i can, how do i concactenate the number on to the name of the constant AND have it recognized by the java interpreter in the correct way?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your autoincrement primary key starts and ends with your x values..Than its possible using Cursors

Comment: You can using reflection. Isn't to much complicated, wait a moment and I will show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question whether you are able to change the constants. If you can, it would be better if you could put the statements in an array.

```
String[] _BLDG_INSERT = {"<SQL insert statement>",   // 0
                         "<SQL insert statement>",   // 1
                         ...
                         "<SQL insert statement>"    // 28
                        };
```

And then you can just access them like this.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 28; x = x+1){
    db.execSQL(DBConstants._BLDG_INSERT[x]);
}
```

Or better still:

```
for(String s : DBConstants._BLDG_INSERT) {
    db.execSQL(s);
}
```

Comment: That's BRILLIANT...i should've thought of the array thing...couldn't see the array forest for the class trees (grin). THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ArrayList<String> getAllRecord()
{
    ArrayList<String> total = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor1 = null;
    try
    {
        cursor1 = getDBobject().rawQuery(
                "select * from "
                + Your table name + ";", null);
        if (cursor1.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String cid = cursor1.getString(1);
                total.add(cid);

            }
            while (cursor1.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("" + TAG + " :" + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cursor1 != null && !cursor1.isClosed())
        {
            cursor1.close();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

This will return you all the datas according to your insertion order

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class testeReflection {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        Class aClass = MyClass.class;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            try {
                Field field = aClass.getField("VAR" + i);

                String s = (String)field.get(myClass);

                System.out.println("myClass[" + i + "] = " + s);                
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(testeReflection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(testeReflection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyClass{
        public static final String VAR0 = "VARIAVEL 01";
        public static final String VAR1 = "VARIAVEL 02";
        public static final String VAR2 = "VARIAVEL 03";
        public static final String VAR3 = "VARIAVEL 04";
        public static final String VAR4 = "VARIAVEL 05";
    }
}
```